# Fully responsive progress bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have to create a progress bar that has to be fully responsive. In order to be responsive I don't want the progress bar class to have a fixed width, but when I put auto in width, line of progress bar is detached from the star also if I give to them auto width

Fixed width: look good
[image]

Width auto
[image]

First how can I fix this issue, and perhaps someone can help me achieve this progress bar to be responsive on mobile also so that the line of progress bar will be vertical.

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: 750px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.progress-bar .step {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress-bar .step .bullet {
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.progress-bar .step:last-child .bullet:before,
.progress-bar .step:last-child .bullet::after {
  display: none;
}

.progress-bar .step .bullet:before,
.progress-bar .step .bullet::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  right: -136px;
  bottom: 11px;
  width: 142px;
  background: #C1C1C1;
}

.active-bullet {
  z-index: 1;
}

.active-check {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="step">

    <div class="bullet active-bullet">
      <img src="star-pb-active.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="check active-check" style="
            border-bottom: 2px solid black;
            padding: 2px;
            DISPLAY: table-cell;
            LEFT: 40px;
            POSITION: relative;
        ">Order placed</div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">

    <div class="bullet">
      <img src="star-pb.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="check">Jewerly Creation</div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">

    <div class="bullet">
      <img src="star-pb.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="check">Packing & Quality Control</div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">

    <div class="bullet">
      <img src="star-pb.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="check">Shipped</div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">

    <div class="bullet">
      <img src="star-pb.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="check">Estimated Delivery</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Option 1)  instead of showing horizontal bar , show vertical bar like flipkart delivery status which is both srcreen same.              option 2)set display :inline-block when desktop and when mobile set div to display:block , so that it show vertical

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI ok, but what about responsivity of progress bar. Can you help me achieve this? Moreover if I do the second option you write the bar of progress cause a issue

Comment: Are you tied to that specific HTML? This seems like an ordered list (`<ol>`) would be more semantic, though I understand that changing HTML isn't always possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try taking a look at the [flex-grow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) from Flexbox.
By giving `display: flex` to the parent, and `flex-grow: 1` to the children, you should be able to make every step be the same size and take all the width of their container.

Comment: In my example the parent is the class step ? because I do but not work

Comment: No, the parent is the 'progress-bar' div. But you'll have to change a bit your css so it isn't the :after property to draw lines. Maybe try using a border ;)

Answer (score 1):

It works the way you want, in fixed or auto width.

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.progress-bar .step {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  isolation: isolate;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress-bar .step::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 3px;
  top: 12px;  /* 1/2 of .bullet's height */
  width: 100%;
  background: #C1C1C1;
}

.progress-bar .step:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.progress-bar .step .bullet {
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active-bullet {
  z-index: 1;
}

.active-check {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Added pseudo element on the parent of `.bullet`.
Also you don't need `::before`, one of those pseudo elements was enough.

Comment: Nice thanks. How can I rotate this bar to be vertical on mobile. I can't find the property to do that according to your css code

Comment: Sorry I forgot that. It's not a big deal. You can use `flex-direction: column` to make container layout vertically and also replace `width`'s value with `height` on `::after`. If you want to use `gap` property on progress-bar, consider adding that gap to height of pseudo-element like this: `::after { height: calc(100% + var(--flex-gap)) }`

Answer (score 0):

try below code, your code some confusion.

1. use flex in css
2. below sample add one button which goes your activity to next step
3. it is fully responsive - on desktop this code horizontal and on mobile this code show vertical progressbar.
4. just use small js, css and for tick icon font awesome js.
   if any query comment it.

```js
let step = 'step1';

const step1 = document.getElementById('step1');
const step2 = document.getElementById('step2');
const step3 = document.getElementById('step3');
const step4 = document.getElementById('step4');

function next() {
  if (step === 'step1') {
    step = 'step2';
    step1.classList.remove("is-active");
    step1.classList.add("is-complete");
    step2.classList.add("is-active");

  } else if (step === 'step2') {
    step = 'step3';
    step2.classList.remove("is-active");
    step2.classList.add("is-complete");
    step3.classList.add("is-active");

  } else if (step === 'step3') {
    step = 'step4d';
    step3.classList.remove("is-active");
    step3.classList.add("is-complete");
    step4.classList.add("is-active");

  } else if (step === 'step4d') {
    step = 'complete';
    step4.classList.remove("is-active");
    step4.classList.add("is-complete");

  } else if (step === 'complete') {
    step = 'step1';
    step4.classList.remove("is-complete");
    step3.classList.remove("is-complete");
    step2.classList.remove("is-complete");
    step1.classList.remove("is-complete");
    step1.classList.add("is-active");
  }
}
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
.progress-bar .progress-track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #dfe3e4;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progress-bar .progress-step {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
.progress-bar .progress-step:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}

.progress-bar .progress-step:before {
  content: "\f00c";
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 4px solid #dfe3e4;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: transparent;
}
.progress-bar .progress-step:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transition: width 1s ease-in;
  height: 5px;
  background: #dfe3e4;
  z-index: -1;
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
    .progress-bar {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .progress-bar .progress-track {
      position: absolute;
      top: -10px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 5px;
      background-color: #dfe3e4;
      z-index: -1;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    .progress-bar .progress-step {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .progress-bar .progress-step:last-child:after {
      display: none;
    }

    .progrestext
    {
      left: 44px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
    }
    .progress-bar .progress-step:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      left: 0%;
      width: 0%;
      transition: width 1s ease-in;
      height: 5px;
      background: #dfe3e4;
      z-index: -1;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
}

.progress-bar .progress-step.is-active {
  color: #2183dd;
}
.progress-bar .progress-step.is-active:before {
  border: 4px solid #777;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
.progress-bar .progress-step.is-complete {
  color: #009900;
}
.progress-bar .progress-step.is-complete:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #009900;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}
.progress-bar .progress-step.is-complete:after {
  background: #2183dd;
  animation: nextStep 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(33, 131, 221, 0.8);
  }
  70% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(33, 131, 221, 0);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(33, 131, 221, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes nextStep {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.container {
  margin: 50px 100px;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c47bc38e87.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track"></div>
    <div id="step1" class="progress-step">
      <div class="progrestext">placed</div>
    </div>
    <div id="step2" class="progress-step">
      <div class="progrestext">Creation</div>
    </div>
    <div id="step3" class="progress-step">
      <div class="progrestext">Packing</div>
    </div>
    <div id="step4" class="progress-step">
      <div class="progrestext">Delivered</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button onClick=next()>Next Step</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice Thanks, but what about flex direction of column in mobile. I apply column direction but the bar is still horizontal, I need in vertical on mobile

Comment: i made some changes

Comment: Your changes affect DT style. I need horizontal line on DT and vertical line on MB

Comment: what is DT and what is MB

Comment: Desktop and mobile

Comment: @media screen and (max-width:700px) { // New style here  }   and old style out of this bracket

Comment: Two questions: 1) Where in your code I can change the size of progress bar . 2)where in your code I can change the progress bar to be horizontal for example because you don't use flex so it's more complicated. Please take example from your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249394/discussion-between-rony-cohen-and-mayur-sancheti).

Comment: now i made some changes in code , which is works on both . make new empty file and try this code.  and remember javascript tag code at end of file.